# How to change brace position in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I am using the IntelliJ IDEA ide for java coding. By default it produces curly braces on the same line as the function name, like so:

```
function bla() {
..
}
```

Can i change it somewhere there so that i will do this instead?:

```
function bla() 
{
..
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the [IntelliJ documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/code-style-java.html#d43133e298):

Go to the menu File | Settings | Project Settings | Code Style - Java. Select the 'Wrapping and braces' tab. Set 'Braces placement options' to 'Next line'.

Comment: I had to go to File > Settings then search for `Code Style` in IDEA 2016.1.

Comment: Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java is another route, at least in 2016.2.

Comment: didn't worked for me (yes, I copied the new style into the Project's)

Comment: what i want is curly brace at end of function name and then a newline, e.g. `function foo(){ \n\n`

Comment: Is it possible to update existing code with new rules? This worked for me when writing new code, but not any old code. [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/1520421/how-to-update-existing-curly-brace-positions-in-intellij-idea?noredirect=1#comment2302930_1520421)

Comment: Do you know how can I add these settings for languages that don't have them by default? I need to change 'wrapping and braces' for ERB file, but the only options are tab and indent size. Maybe for these languages they are inherited from somewhere? Probably yes, yes they are, inherited from Ruby of course. If someone has this problem  check the "parent" language settings

Answer (score 10):

Here is the exact working path. I have added screenshot with explanations.

[image: Screenshot "How to change braces position in Intelli]