# How to update existing curly brace positions in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, formatting

I've been given Java code by others which use curly braces on new lines, and I'd like them on the same line after I import the file without having to change them line-by-line?

How do I do it?

```
private void someMethod()
{
   //Some code here
}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
private void someMethod(){
   //The same code
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to google this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change brace position in IntelliJ IDE?](https://superuser.com/questions/791586/how-to-change-brace-position-in-intellij-ide)

Comment: @AulisRonkainen No, this isn't the same. That post explains how to change brace positions, but I'm asking specifically about files that are already written. Let me know if you've figured it out. Thank you!